# Best way to measure 0-5V with uController running on 3.3V

Tags: adc, stm32f4

What is best way to accurately measure 0-5V with uController running on 3.3V?

It will work in environment with quite a big delta temp (from -20 °C to 80 °C).

I use stm32F4 12 bit ADC.

1. precise resistor divider 5-25 ppm/K, ADC from uC
2. some kind of op amp
3. external ADC running at 5V + 5V ref voltage
4. other?

Comment: "Accurately" has very little meaning here.  You need to tell us how accurate you need to be, and then we can tell you how to achieve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would try a resistor divider.  If you get an array the relative R's will track better than the absolute value.  [Here](http://www.susumu.co.jp/product_pdf/all-list/e_09-10.pdf) is one random selection from DK.

Answer (score 2):

12 bits gives you 244ppm from one possible value to the next, assuming exactly constant temperature, voltage, and everything else.  There's little point in making your circuit better than that, or perhaps half that.

(1 / (2^12)) * 1M = 244

16 stable, noise-free bits would give you 15ppm, or -96dBFS.  (decibels referenced to full-scale)

18 perfect bits would give you 4ppm, or -108dBFS.

I would definitely suggest an external 20-bit ADC or better with tight-tolerance/low-value resistors, low-noise opamps if used, and careful attention to layout/routing to avoid picking up external noise.

---

### Edit:

One thing that might save you in some ways, but not others, is the ability to oversample by a *lot*.  As in several hundred times.  Basically, you:

1. Add uncorrelated, high-frequency noise to the signal.  (Yes, I'm serious, keep reading.)  This noise should cover a maximum of 2 native LSB's in level (out of 12 native bits in your case) and be entirely above the bandwidth of the signal so that it can be removed later.
2. Run the ADC fast enough to capture the noise as well as the signal.
3. Lowpass (average) the ADC readings.  This removes the noise and fills in the lower bits that the ADC can't distinguish on its own.
4. (optional) Throw away most of the samples because they're not really needed after the lowpass.  Keep just enough to represent the signal accurately.

Depending on how quickly your signal is changing, this may allow you to use the internal 12-bit ADC to end up with 18-bit accuracy.  However, you still have to be careful that the external circuit does not add more than 1/2 final LSB of noise at the frequencies that you want to measure, while providing about 1 native LSB of noise at higher frequencies.

Delta-Sigma or Sigma-Delta ADC's (order doesn't matter) do all of this internally and are specified according to their final resolution.  The actual ADC isn't much to be proud of except possibly in sample rate.  The detailed operation is slightly different than what I described here, but the concept works exactly the same way.

Answer (score 1):

The divider will work but you could add an op-amp after the voltage divider in a voltage follower configuration, powered by 3.3v to limit current flowing into the stm32f4 or being pulled away from your circuit.

I haven't done this myself but I believe the stm32f4 has internal op-amps that could be used. It would cut down on external components.

Answer (score 1):

> What is best way to accurately measure 0-5V with uController running
>   on 3.3V?

- How accurate is the ADC voltage reference you are using?
- How good is the internal ADC on dc offset, gain error and INL?

"Best accuracy" **certainly** means an external ADC wheras adequate accuracy might be OK with internal ADC and an external precise voltage reference. Acceptable accuracy might mean internal voltage reference and internal ADC.

Once you have decided this, then you can decide on the resistor ratio and its tolerance and drift characteristic.